Wireguard Proxy : port 443 forwarded but not port 80
Summary : Port 80 and 443 traffic arrives to my VPS but only port 443 traffic is forwarded by Wireguard to my homelab.
I recently invested in a cheap VPS. The main objective was to use it as a proxy and redirect all incoming traffic on ports 80 and 443 to my Raspberry Pi using a Wireguard tunnel. Ports 80 and 443 on my Pi are bound to Traefik which distributes requests to Docker containers.
Everything was working pretty well when I noticed that the Traefik http to https redirect was not working. I am able to access to my applications using https but no http requests are resolved or redirected to https requests as they should be.
I ended up doing tcpdump checks everywhere. I found out that port 80 and 443 requests both arrived to my VPS but that only port 443 requests were forwarded by Wireguard. All my configuration is detailed behind with the results of the tests I did.
Would you mind looking upon my case and help me find out what is not working ?
Many thanks.
Wireguard Configuration (wg0.conf)
[Interface]

Address = 10.10.10.1/24

ListenPort = 51820

PrivateKey = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

PostUp = /etc/wireguard/iptables.sh

PostDown = /etc/wireguard/iptables.sh

[Peer]

PublicKey = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.10/32

iptables rules (iptables.sh)
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.10:443

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.10:80

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

(net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 is already set elsewhere)
tcpdump checks
(VPS Tunnel IP : 10.10.10.1, Homelab Tunnel IP : 10.10.10.10 )
Check one : HTTP
laptop shell : curl http://mydomain.test
-> curl: (28) Failed to connect to mydomain.test port 80 after 13283 ms: Couldn't connect to server
shell 1, VPS : sudo tcpdump -nnSX port 80
-> 22 packets captured, ...
shell 2, VPS : sudo tcpdump -n -X -i wg0 host 10.10.10.10
-> 3 packets captured, ...
Check two : HTTPS
laptop shell : curl https://mydomain.test
-> [service homepage]
shell 1, VPS : sudo tcpdump -nnSX port 443
-> 55 packets captured, ...
shell 2, VPS : sudo tcpdump -n -X -i wg0 host 10.10.10.10
-> 55 packets captured, ...
